# Why properties are always said to be made nonatomic in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

It is said that `nonatomic` option will make your **setter method** run faster. I googled it but am not able to understand. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties?rq=1

Comment: Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32942413/1961064

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Declaring a property `atomic` makes compiler generate additional code that prevents concurrent access to the property. This additional code locks a semaphore, then gets or sets the property, and then unlock the semaphore. Compared to setting or getting a primitive value or a pointer, locking and unlocking a semaphore is expensive (although it is usually negligible if you consider the overall flow of your app).

Since most of your classes under iOS, especially the ones related to UI, will be used in a single-threaded environment, it is safe to drop `atomic` (i.e. write `nonatomic`, because properties are `atomic` by default): even though the operation is relatively inexpensive, you do not want to pay for things that you do not need.

Comment: 1+ The part about it being safe to drop atomic for UI properties since it should always be updated on the main thread anyway

Comment: You might want to clarify that in order to "drop" `atomic`, you have to explicitly use `nonatomic` because `atomic` is the default setting for properties; if you don't specify anything, you get `atomic`.

Answer (score 7):

see the difference between atomic and nonatomic in objective c

**Atomic**

Atomic is the default behaviour for a property; by not explicitly setting the above property as nonatomic, it will be atomic.

An atomic property adds a level of thread safety when getting or setting values. That is, the getter and setter for the property will always be fully completed regardless of what other threads are doing. The trade-off is that these properties will be a little slower to access than a nonatomic equivalent.

**Non-Atomic**

Nonatomic properties are not thread safe, and will return their properties directly. This will be faster than atomic properties, but obviously carries some risk if precautions aren’t made.

Comment: > 'will ensure the present process is completed by the cpu, before another process access the variable'


doesn't this imply thread safety?

Comment: I have the same question than @powerj1984

Answer (score 3):

```
@property (strong) NSString *str;
```

**Atomic** is the default behaviour for a property; by not explicitly setting the above property as nonatomic, it will be atomic.

setter & getter for these **Atomic** property

```
-(NSString *) str{
@synchronized(self){
return str;
}}

-(void) setStr: (NSString *) newString {
@synchronized(self)  {
str = newString;
}}
```

An atomic property adds a level of thread safety when getting or setting values. That is, the getter and setter for the property will always be fully completed regardless of what other threads are doing. these properties will be a little slower to access than a nonatomic equivalent.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *str;
```

**Nonatomic** properties are not thread safe, and will return their properties directly. This will be faster than atomic properties, but obviously carries some risk if precautions aren’t made.

setter & getter for these **Nonatomic** property

```
-(NSString *) str{
    return str;
    }}

-(void) setStr: (NSString *) newString{
str = newString;
}
```

So by looking on the setter & getter methods for both **Atomic & nonatomic** that nonatomic methods are very light weight.

Comment: Your code would only work under ARC.  Because ARC guarantees atomicity on object assignment, that latter example is actually atomic.   Note that `NSString` properties should always be declared as `copy`.